# wordpress blog, is there a way to make anyone post in a blog without having login info

Tags: forms

I am creating a wordpress blog site with some custom function. One on the thing that I need to do to have a function where user can post to blog without using login information. Is that doable? I know this will create lots of spam stuff, but this is what the owner of the site wants.

Answer (score 1):

[gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) (not free) and [TDO mini forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) plugins can enable this fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [openID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) and [openID-related plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=openid&sort=), I think this is a feasible way for you.